# Recursion counter doesn't work in codewars kata

Tags: javascript, recursion

Currently trying to complete the [persistent bugger kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55bf01e5a717a0d57e0000ec/train/javascript) in code wars.

I need to return the number of times the input has to be multiplied until it is reduced to a single number (full task instructions below).

Everything appears to work apart from the count. when I console log, the number of times it logs and runs is correct, but instead of incrementing such as 1,2,3 it will be something like 2,2,4.

So instead of returning 3, it returns 4.

I try to not ask for help with katas, but this time I am completely at a loss as to why the count is firstly skipping numbers and also not incrementing.

> **Task:**
>
> Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.
>
> **For example:**
>
> ```
>  persistence(39) === 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
>                        // and 4 has only one digit
>                  
>  persistence(999) === 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
>                         // 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2
>                   
>  persistence(4) === 0 // because 4 is already a one-digit number
> ```

My function:

```js
function persistence(num) {
  //console.log('here', num)
  if(num < 10) return 0;
  if(num === 25) return 2
  let spl = num.toString().split('');
  
  let result = 1;
  let count = 1;

  spl.forEach((s) => {
    let int = parseInt(s)
    result *= int;
    //count++;
  })
  
  //console.log(result)
  if(result > 9) {
    persistence(result)
    count++;
  }
  
 // console.log('count-->', count)
  return count;
}
```

A sub issue is that the input 25 always returns a count 1 less than it should. My fix is poor I know, again any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You only increment `count` once regardless of how many times `persistence()` is called in `if (result > 9) { ... }`

Comment: Would count not increment each time the if statement is true? If not how come?

Comment: There is a separate `count` variable every time you recursively call the function. There isn't a single `count` that all invocations work with.

Comment: `persistence()` returns `count`. Use that return value to calculate the actual result.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you show me and example?

Comment: `persistence()` is executed -> `count = 1`. If `result > 9` you have to call `persistence()` again -> `count++`. But what if that "inner" `persistence()` has to call `persistence()` again because its `result` is still `> 9`? The `count` variable is only available in `persistence` and not in any of the "inner" calls so the `count` variable from the first/outer `persistence()` is not aware of any of the "inner" `persistence()` calls. But you already added part of the solution in the function - you tell the caller the value of `count` (`return count;`). You just have to use that knowledge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoiler alert: this contains a solution. If you don't want that, stop before the end.

You don't really want to work with count, since as people point out, it's a local variable. You also don't work too hard to special case the result if it's a single digit. Let the recursion handle it.

Thus:

```
  function persistence(num) {
  //console.log('here', num)
  if(num < 10) return 0;
  //still here, must be 2 or more digits
  let spl = num.toString().split('');
  
  let result = 1;

  spl.forEach((s) => {
    let int = parseInt(s)
    result *= int;
  })


 
  //console.log(result)
  
    return 1 + persistence(result)
  
}
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. I hadnt even thought about letting recursion deal with the condition for me either. really appreciate the help and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a complete solution posted here with fixes to your implementation, I will offer what I think is a simpler version.  If we had a function to create the digit product for us, then `persistence` could be this simple recursion:

```js
const persistence = (n) => 
  n < 10 ? 0 : 1 + persistence (digProduct (n))
```

You already have code for the digit product, and while it's fine, a mathematical approach, rather than a string-base one, is somewhat cleaner.  We could write it -- also recursively -- like

```js
const digProduct = (n) => 
  n < 10 ? n : (n % 10) * digProduct (Math .floor (n / 10))
```

or instead we might choose `(n / 10) | 0` in place of the `floor` call.  Either is reasonable.

Putting it together, we have:

```js
const digProduct = (n) => 
  n < 10 ? n : (n % 10) * digProduct ((n / 10) | 0)

const persistence = (n) => 
  n < 10 ? 0 : 1 + persistence (digProduct (n))

const tests = [39, 999, 4, 25]
tests.forEach (n => console.log (`${n} --> ${persistence(n)}`))
```